# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I have no idea why this error is happening. I have imported the facebook ios sdk static library and I get that error. What could be causing it?

Thanks for any help guys

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Facebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to link whatever library this Facebook class is implemented in.

Comment: How did you fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker can't find symbols related to class Facebook.

A good first place to look would be to check whether there is a simulator (x86) build of the SDK included in your project.  Usually XCode takes care of selecting the right architecture for you, but it's possible you just have the ARMv7 version.

Care to share the command-line for the linker with us?  (you can get this by selecting the log tab in the project navigator - it's the rightmost - and then drilling down to get the command-line for each build action.)

Comment: I just updated the post with more information. Tell me if that is what you meant?

Comment: Looks as though the library isn't being linked.   Another possibility to check:
- Select your project in the project navigator
- Select the target in the project editor 
- Select the 'Build Phases' [?] tab 
- Look for 'Link with libraries and Frameworks' or similar
- CHeck whether the library is in the list.  If not, add it. 

[Apologies for the vagueness of the descriptions of the UI - haven't got my development machine with me here]

Comment: To add to this, just because your library is listed in the project navigator doesn't mean it's actually build against.

Comment: That was pretty much the problem. xcode can be confusing sometimes ey. Thanks guys!